# Is there a possibility to make bottom scrollbar fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pretty large table on my site with bottom scrollbar (overflow) and this scroll is absolutely necessery thing. But when number of rows grows up, table heigh also becomes a problem and it is not user friendly to make someone scroll page down to the bottom every time.

Is there a possibility to make bottom scrollbar fixed so user won`t need to scroll page to the bottom? I tried Google search, but found asolutely nothing.

Comment: Please provide your  code.

Comment: Hello, please profile a snippet or jsfiddle so people can clearly see what you're doing and have something to work with.

Comment: If you let the table overflow directly on the body, the scrollbar should be fixed to the viewport. Otherwise make sure the container in which the tables overflows is 'attached' to the viewport.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Tq3Rg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and it's pretty easy

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.clientHeight;
```

Call this line when your DOM is fully load (end of your body or throught an event).

you can replace document.body by another element if your scroll is not on the body.

```
<table id="myTable">
...
<script>
  var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
  myTable.scrollTop = myTable.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a litle, I am not familiar with JS at all. I need to put this code     <script>
  var myTable = document.getElementById('table_1');
  myTable.scrollTop = myTable.clientHeight;</script>    right after my table? Then what I am need to do with this:     document.body.scrollTop = document.body.clientHeight; if I want to make my bottom scrollbar fixed automatically without any user action. I mean table loads with already fixed scrollbar and that is all. Sorry for newbie questions

Comment: provide me some part of your code and I will be abble to make you understand.

Comment: I`ll be glad to give you a code, but it as actually a coplex tables plugin. So maybe you can check this page and it helps  https://profitov_net/tatables/ Thank you a lot

Comment: It is a test page with sample lable